# Convert PostgreSQL query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, split, database-migration

I need to convert my query

```
select 
    unnest(string_to_array(names, ',')) as "Admin Name",
    unnest(string_to_array(phones, ',')) as "Admin Phone",
    unnest(string_to_array(emails, ',')) as "Admin Emails"
from 
    metadata_Table
```

to an equivalent SQL Server query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Storing name/phones/emails as comma separated values violates 1NF(atomicity).  I would consider refactoring the table. Anyway [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) may be helpful

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exactly this easily in SL Server.  There is no "string_split() with ordinality".  And, the ordering is not guaranteed with `string_split()`.

Until Microsoft enhances this functions, my suggestion is a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as name, convert(varchar(max), null) as phone, convert(varchar(max), null) as email,
             convert(varchar(max), names + ',') as names_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), phones + ',') as phones_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), emails + ',') as emails_rest,
             0 as lev
      from metadata_Table
      union all
      select left(names_rest, charindex(',', names_rest) - 1),
             left(phones_rest, charindex(',', phones_rest) - 1),
             left(emails_rest, charindex(',', emails_rest) - 1),
             stuff(names_rest, 1, charindex(',', names_rest), ''),
             stuff(phones_rest, 1, charindex(',', phones_rest), ''),
             stuff(emails_rest, 1, charindex(',', emails_rest), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where emails_rest like '%,%'
     )
select *
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.
 this is what I get

Comment: @noyraz No one, including you, should be using the text datatype at this late date. Change your schema now, before you get so far that this change requires even more work.